# MySQL query to do a SELF join and perform aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a requirement to get the data from mysql db.
below is the DDL, DML ,sample output and query.
I need help on optimizing the query, because I am sure the query I have wrote is very basic.

```
create table team (
team_id int,
team_name char(10)
);

create table matches (
matches_id int,
host_team_id int,
guest_team_id int,
host_goals int,
guest_goals int
);


insert into team values (10, 'mumbai');
insert into team values (20, 'delhi');
insert into team values (30, 'banglore');
insert into team values (40, 'chennai');
insert into team values (50, 'gujarat');
insert into matches values (1, 50, 20, 2,1); 
insert into matches values (2, 30, 40, 2,0); 
insert into matches values (3, 10, 50, 1,1); 
insert into matches values (4, 20, 30, 0,1); 
insert into matches values (5, 40, 20, 3,2); 
insert into matches values (6, 50, 30, 1,0); 
insert into matches values (7, 40, 10, 1,2);
```

---

### **-- rules**

-- team with more goals wins and gets 3points
-- team which lose gets 0points
-- for a tie, each team gets 1point

---

### **expected output [order by goals and then by team_name**

```
team_id |   team_name | goals
50          gujarat     7
30          bangalore   6
10          mumbai      4
40          chennai     3
20          delhi       0
```

---

### **QUERY**

```
select * from (select team_id, team_name, sum(goals) as goals from (
select team_id, team_name,  
 SUM(  Case
  when host_goals > guest_goals then 3
  when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
  else  0
  end ) as goals
from team t , matches m1
where t.team_id = m1.host_team_id
group by team_id, team_name

union all

select team_id, team_name,  
 SUM(  Case
  when guest_goals  > host_goals then 3
  when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
  else  0
  end ) as goals
from team t , matches m1
where t.team_id = m1.guest_team_id
group by team_id, team_name
order by goals desc, team_name asc) as finalOut
group by team_id, team_name ) as t1
order by goals desc, team_name asc
```

Comment: You should not call the "points"  you are defining as "goals".  These are different things and calling it "goals" is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use better criteria instead of having to `union` two queries. Forget the `union all` and do this:

```
select team_id, team_name,  
 SUM(
     (t.team_id = m1.host_team_id) * ((host_goals >= guest_goals) + 2 * (host_goals > guest_goals)) +
     (t.team_id = m1.guest__team_id) * ((host_goals <= guest_goals) + 2 * (host_goals < guest_goals)) 

 ) as goals
from team t , matches m1
where ((t.team_id = m1.host_team_id) or (t.team_id = m1.guest_team_id))
group by team_id, team_name
```

This should be a good starting point. (untested)

Comment: Thanks for the solution,it works perfectly with one "order by" condition. however I am keen to know the condition you used inside SUM ( (condition1) * (condition2 +2 ) * ( condition3 ) ....)  . I haven't seen such way of putting down the conditions.Could you explain more about it.

Comment: @JforJava, off course. A logical expression is evaluated to 0 (false) or 1 (true). (t.team_id = m1.host_team_id) * something means that if the condition of equality is true, then the value will be something. Otherwise 0 (false). (host_goals >= guest_goals) + 2 * (host_goals > guest_goals) means that if greater or equal, then 1 + 2 if greater. So, if it is smaller, then it will be 0, if it is equal, then 1 * 1 + 2 * 0 = 1 and if greater, then 3. It is a mixture of arithmetics and boolean algebra which fits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the sum, group by and order by  only on the most external select

```
  select * from (select team_id, team_name, sum(goals) as goals from (
  select 
      team_id
    , team_name
    , Case
        when host_goals > guest_goals then 3
        when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
        else  0
      end  as goals
  from team t 
  Inner join matches m1 on  t.team_id = m1.host_team_id

  union all

  select 
      team_id
    , team_name
    , Case
        when guest_goals  > host_goals then 3
        when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
        else  0
      end  
  from team t 
  inner join matches m1 on t.team_id = m1.guest_team_id
  ) as finalOut
  group by team_id, team_name 
  order by goals desc, team_name asc
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for radical simplification:

```
select t.team_id, t.team_name, sum(points) as points
from teams t join
     ((select host_team_id as team_id, host_goals as goals, 'host' as which,
              (case when host_goals > guest_goals then 3
                    when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
                    else 0
               end) as points
       from matches
      ) union all
      (select guest_team_id as team_id, guest_goals as goals, 'guest' as which
              (case when guest_goals > host_goals then 3
                    when guest_goals = host_goals then 1
                    else 0
               end) as points
       from matches
      )
     ) hg
     on hg.team_id = t.team_id
group by t.team_id, t.team_name
order by sum(points) desc, team_name;
```

If you want all teams -- even those who have played no matches -- then use `left join`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.